# How to stop single clicks or ctrl+click from opening two tabs

Tags: mouse, click-policy

For a few weeks now my Ubuntu install 18.04 routinely opens **two** tabs instead of one when I perform a single slick or a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>. I have tried adjusted the mouse speed in Devices > Mouse & Touchpad but this has no effect.

What is responsible for this behaviour and how can I fix it?  I am running the GNOME shell window manager.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse, or tried to use a trackpad if available?

Comment: sounds like faulty mouse microswtich (probably chinese omrons which are very poor quality - something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDoXMJyimDU)

Comment: @EdiD Its a Logitech mouse made in China, like everything else these days. I've been using it for a year or so though.